# Router is not forwarding packets

Tags: networking, routing, forwarding

So I have the following setup:

```
      (Net-1: 64.236.5.112/30)                  (Net-2: 64.236.5.12/30)

64.236.5.113/30        64.236.5.114/30     64.236.5.13/30        64.236.5.14/30
Router1 <------------------------> Router2 <------------------------> Router3
```

The Router1 and Router2 have a default route (`ip route add default via <IP-of-next-router>`) to the respective interface of router3 that is in their network.

IP forwarding is enabled on all three routers.
I can ping both router1 and router2 from router3

But when I try to ping router3 from router1 and vice versa, the ICMP-request packet gets stuck on router2 and doesn't get forwarded through to the next network.

I feel like I am missing something quite obvious but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Router3 doesn't know Router1 network, thus Router3 is sending traffic to its default gw. Add static route to Router3 to reach Router1 network.

Comment: You mean adding `ip route add 64.236.5.113 via 64.236.5.13` to router3? And the same for router1 of course? Unfortunately this gave the same result. `ip route add 64.236.5.112/30 via 64.236.5.13` also made not difference.